# How to retrive data from another DataTable than the one bind to DataGrid.ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, datagrid, datatable

I use SQLiteDatabase.
I create table and fill to DataTable in C#.
I have DataTable for every table in database.
In WPF programming, 
I bind DataTable to DataGrid.ItemsSource
then I can do every task such as List, Add, Edit, Delete.

but the problem is
I don't know how to do something like "left outer join".
such as
I have table "Product" that have ID, Name.
and table "Order" that have ProductID.
so if I bind "Order" to DataGrid.ItemsSource
I can show just the "ProductID" not the Name of it.

I think about "Converter".
I try to search in the internet, 
I can just Convert value to something no need outside data.
I don't know how to get Product DataTable from my object.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to replicate your SQL environment in code and you are thinking that DataTables are the way to do this.  If I am correct, there are better tools to use such as Entity Framework.

Comment: @KingKing there should be a `Best Comment Ever` badge in StackOverflow.